# Can I install exodus 'wallet' for ethereum & bitcoin on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, bitcoin, ethereum

[This](https://www.exodus.io/releases/) looks a neat programme for managing cryptocurrency on Linux

I've been using Ubuntu for 3 or 4 years, used the terminal parrot fashion for various functions and installs, but have v. little knowledge.

Does anyone think this would run on Ubuntu and if so, how could I install it?

Or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Exodus co-founder here... You can place the folder wherever you like. We recommend just dropping it in your home directory. You can then run Exodus by just double-clicking on the `Exodus` program or by running it directly from the terminal: `./Exodus`.

Long-term, we'll probably offer a `.deb` so that it can easily be installed in the proper location. Also, note that it'll only run on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your replies, sounds straightforward. Looking forward to it. Andrew

Comment: I put the folder in the home directory and the exodus program icon doesn't work.

Comment: Any time frame for that .deb? A ppa would also be great.

Comment: No ETA yet - but the topic does come up during our development meetings. It just came up a few days ago. The general plan is to nail down the UX and ship in-app opt-in auto-updates first, then we'll revisit this. A lot of our employees are Linux users so there is strong internal championing of Linux packaging.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for such a solid wallet! I have a bash script that I use to install everything on my Ubuntu dev machine (regularly cycled), so was wondering whether you guys have a terminal command to grab the latest build rather than downloading it each time? Thanks a lot for your great work :) Rob

Comment: @RobHendricks thanks for the kind words. We don't have a command for this, but you could whip one up pretty easily and create a cron job. 

1. Set your cron job to monitor https://updates.exodus.io/releases/feed/darwin.json for the latest version. I realize this is for macOS, but we release all platforms at the same time.

2. You'll get the version from this file. Then download the linux deb e.g. https://downloads.exodus.io/releases/exodus_20.9.11_amd64.deb

3. Download the hash file. e.g. https://downloads.exodus.io/releases/hashes-exodus-20.9.11.txt

4. Check hash and install.

Comment: ^^ -- for extra security, you could add the GPG key to your keyring and verify that the hashes file is actually published from us. Also, if you create a script to do all of this, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

This'll cover you for install (and update if you Cron as discussed above)... Wanted to add this as a reply to @JP Richards, but I'm not with enough reps yet (help a brother out, guys) :)

https://github.com/robotard/ExodusUpdater/

Grab the exodus.sh file, and 'sudo ./exodus.sh'...

It will always check if you have the latest or any version installed, and download and install the most recent .deb :)